# python, better syntax with multiprocesses

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have the following method:

```
def GetMarketData(fr, cr, dct1, dct2, dict3, dct5, dct5):
    md = MarketData()

    q1 = Queue()
    q2 = Queue()
    q3 = Queue()
    q4 = Queue()
    q5 = Queue()
    q6 = Queue()
    q7 = Queue()
    p1 = Process(target=md.GetMD1, args=(q1,))
    p2 = Process(target=md.GetMD2, args=(q2,))
    p3 = Process(target=md.GetMD3, args=(q3,))
    p4 = Process(target=md.GetMD4, args=(q4,))
    p5 = Process(target=md.GetMD5, args=(q5,))
    p6 = Process(target=md.GetMD6, args=(q6,))
    p7 = Process(target=md.GetMD7, args=(q7,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()
    p5.start()
    p6.start()
    p7.start()
    fr.append(q1.get())
    dct1.update(q2.get())
    dct2.update(q3.get())
    dct3.update(q4.get())
    cr.append(q5.get())
    dct4.update(q6.get())
    dct5.update(q7.get())
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    p4.join()
    p5.join()
    p6.join()
    p7.join()

    #print "good"
```

Is there a good way to rewrite this in a few line as possible. If I would need to open the same process over each queue that would not be a problem, but I need to run several different programs in parallel and do not see how to rewrite this in a fewer lines...

Thanks !!!

Comment: what is the family of functions `md.GetMD` doing?  Why are there 7 of them?

Comment: they extract Market Data using different keys, methods are very different but can be run in parallel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first simplification, I'd use lists:

```
def GetMarketData(fr, cr, dct1, dct2, dict3, dct5, dct5):
    md = MarketData()

    ques = [Queue() for _ in range(7)]
    procs = [Process(target=getattr(md,'GetMD%d'%(i),args=(q,)) 
             for i,q in enumerate(ques,1)]
    for p in procs:
        p.start()

    fr.append(ques[0].get())
    dct1.update(ques[1].get())
    dct2.update(ques[2].get())
    dct3.update(ques[3].get())
    cr.append(ques[4].get())
    dct4.update(ques[5].get())
    dct5.update(ques[6].get())

    for p in procs:
        p.join()
```

Comment: the q[x] lines should be replaced by que[x] or rename your que variable to q ;)

Comment: @dweeves -- thanks.  I corrected a couple other minor mistakes while I was at it.

Comment: What's a "que"? Shouldn't that variable be called "queues"? And "p" should be "processes"...

Comment: @boxed -- Sure, OP can name the variables whatever is fitting.  I was just trying to keep the names short enough that it's not tedious to type again and again and to keep the lines slightly shorter ...

Comment: i think and even shorter solution can be found using dictionary (or tuple list) for storing what operation/target is to be done on each queue . however this would complicate a bit the understanding of the code.

Comment: @mgilson: optimizing for writing is not either pythonic or a good programming practice. Especially when talking to newbies it's important to present a culture of readable code!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
q1 = Queue()
q2 = Queue()
q3 = Queue()
q4 = Queue()
q5 = Queue()
q6 = Queue()
q7 = Queue()
```

You can instead write:

```
queues = [Queue() for i in xrange(7)]
```

Now your queues are `queues[0]` through `queues[6]`. You can do the same thing with your processes:

```
processes = [Process(target=getattr("md.GetMD%d" % (i+1)), args=(queues[i],))
             for i in xrange(7)]
```

And then start them using a loop:

```
for process in processes:
    process.start()
```

Similarly for joining later:

```
for process in processes:
    process.join()
```

That leaves this section:

```
fr.append(q1.get())
dct1.update(q2.get())
dct2.update(q3.get())
dct3.update(q4.get())
cr.append(q5.get())
dct4.update(q6.get())
dct5.update(q7.get())
```

Which could be loopified in a similar manner just by accepting any number of arguments in your function rather than named arguments; then we can loop over the arguments:

```
for queue, result_dict in zip(queues, result_dicts):
    result_dict.update(queue.get())
```

Then we can also just make it so we pass in any number of dictionaries, so rather than using the magic number of `7` we just create as many queues and processes as arguments. The function doesn't need to know that some dictionaries are different from others because *in fact they are all processed identically anyway.*

Putting it together, we get:

```
def GetMarketData(*result_dicts):

    queues = [Queue() for item in result_dicts]

    processes = [Process(target=getattr("md.GetMD%d" % (i+1)), args=(queues[i],))
                 for i in xrange(len(result_dicts))]

    for process in processes:
        process.start()

    for queue, result_dict in zip(queues, result_dicts):
        result_dict.update(queue.get())

    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

(Unrelated note: I've not done much with `multiprocessing`, but wouldn't you want to `join` the processes before reading from the queues, to make sure the results in the queues are complete?)

Comment: How did you manage to transform the `.update` calls to `.append` calls?